# SegFault error, but linked list works properly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list, c-strings, alphabetical

I would really like to know why the program compiles and runs smoothly, without giving any disruption or bad results, just a "SegFault" at the very end of the program (as well as another unwanted result).
The program's task is to place single letters in a linked list in alphabetical order. Such struct has to contain the number of times the letter has been detected and, of course, the letter itself.

**INPUT**

`swag`

**OUTPUT**

`aagsw
 Letter: a  Frequency: 1
 Letter: g  Frequency: 1
 Letter: s  Frequency: 1
 Letter: w  Frequency: 1
 Letter: �  Frequency: 194
 Segmentation Fault`

It shouldn't be like this it should be:

`aagsw
 Letter: a  Frequency: 1
 Letter: g  Frequency: 1
 Letter: s  Frequency: 1
 Letter: w  Frequency: 1`

(Captain Obvious, thank me later)

I'll give you the code.

**Issue solved**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char string[30];

typedef struct nodo{
  char chara;
  int freq;
  struct nodo *next;
}Nodo;

typedef Nodo *Lista;

typedef struct{
  int value;
  char chara;
  int freq;
}Lettera;

Lista head;

void Creator(string stringa){

  Lettera letter[26];

  for(int i=0; i < strlen(stringa); i++){ //unnecessary part
    for(int j=0; j < strlen(stringa)-1; j++){
      if((int) stringa[j] > (int) stringa[j+1]){
        char tmp=stringa[j+1];
        stringa[j+1] = stringa[j];
        stringa[j] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%s\n",stringa);
  int k=97;
  for(int i=0; i<26; i++){  //initializing auxiliary struct
    letter[i].chara = (char) k;
    letter[i].value = k;
    letter[i].freq = 0;
    k++;
  }

  for(int i=0; i < strlen(stringa); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<26; j++){
      if(letter[j].chara == stringa[i]){
        letter[j].freq++;
      }
    }
  }

  Lista temp=NULL; //forgot to initialize

  for(int i=25; i>=0; i--){ //wrong index was i=26
    if(letter[i].freq>0){
      head=(Lista) malloc (sizeof(Nodo));
      head->chara = letter[i].chara;
      head->freq = letter[i].freq;
      head->next = temp;
      temp = head;
    }
  }
  while(head != NULL){
    printf("Letter: %c \tFrequency: %d\n", head->chara, head->freq);
    head = head->next;
  }
}

int main(){
  string stringa;
  scanf("%s",stringa);
  Creator(stringa);
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you attempted so far? This may help: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Habras Could you explain how do you have gotten  aagsw from swag ?:)

Comment: A program that compiles without warnings, does not mean that it is logically valid.

Comment: `head->next = temp`. That looks wrong. `temp` is an uninitialised value the first time that line runs. Need to init `Lista temp=NULL;`

Comment: I use atom as text editor, and no, they had shown me some debuggers which I personally dislike. I got aagsw by sorting in alphabetical order, lol

Comment: So find a debugger that you do like. That's an essential tool. You can't debug effectively with just a text editor. Do you plan to post on Stack Overflow every time you have a bug?

Comment: @Habras There is no need to sort the source string. It is enough to add letters to the list in the order by letter codes.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks kaylum, might you give me some advice for a good debugger? I was in need for help and desperate since I couldn't find a solution to such problem, but thanks very much for your response! :) I am looking forward to improving my programming skills, I am sorry to bother experienced programmers with boring posts, but I hope you do understand.

Comment: you're going to struggle mightily and waste mountains of time in your career if `printf` is your only debugging tool. I used to have the same thinking, thought there'd be too much of a learning curve for gdb. One day I finally decided to go for it, within 15 min I was debugging with breakpoints, printing vars, etc. It was marvelous. Still kicking myself for the 3 years I spent with `printf` only. And I'm also curious why "swag" is supposed to produce an output where 'a' has a frequency of 2.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, that sorting was unnecessary, thanks!

Comment: I wrote my first program in a debugger.  Didn't have any compilers/assemblers, but the machine had instructions for breaking into the "debug monitor" and how to use that to write op codes and data to RAM.

Comment: @yano editing it right now, typo mistake

Comment: Thank you guys for your advice, seems I can't only rely on printf. I will provide you better posts from now on, as well as getting better at programming :)

Comment: sometimes `printf` is the best tool for the job, particularly if halting your program destroys/compromises the behavior you're trying to examine. Just a good idea to have as many tools in the toolbox as possible, especially as your programs grow in complexity and functionality.

Comment: Yes, `printf` and pin toggling are two ways to provide diagnostic output, but the art of debugging using just those tools is very time consuming and error prone.  The nice thing about stepping through the code with a debugger, is you'll be able to see the exact cause of the fault much faster.  Diagnostic outputs require a lot of guess-work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, Habras.

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Your approach is too complicated. There is no need to sort the entered string. It is the list that should place letters in order when they are added to the list.

Moreover there are bugs. For example you declared the array `letter` like

```
Lettera letter[26];
```

So the valid range of indices is `[0, 26)`. However in this loop

```
  for(int i=26; i>=0; i--){
    if(letter[i].freq>0){
      head=(Lista) malloc (sizeof(Nodo));
      head->chara = letter[i].chara;
      head->freq = letter[i].freq;
      head->next = temp;
      temp = head;
    }
  }
```

you are trying to access a non-existent element with the index equal to `26`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how letters can be added to the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct nodo
{
    char chara;
    size_t freq;
    struct nodo *next;
} Nodo;

typedef Nodo *Lista;

void initialize( Lista *lista, const char *s )
{
    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        char c = *s;

        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )c ) )
        {
            c = tolower( ( unsigned char )c );

            Nodo **nodo = lista;

            while ( *nodo != NULL && ( *nodo )->chara < c )
            {
                nodo = &( *nodo  )->next;
            }

            if ( *nodo == NULL || c < ( *nodo )->chara )
            {
                Nodo *current = malloc( sizeof( Nodo ) );
                current->chara = c;
                current->freq = 1;
                current->next = *nodo;
                *nodo = current;
            }
            else
            {
                ++( *nodo )->freq;
            }
        }           
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };

    Lista lista = NULL;

    char s[N];
    s[0] = '\0';

    printf( "Enter a text: " );

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    initialize( &lista, s );

    for ( Nodo *current = lista; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "{ %c: %zu } ", current->chara, current->freq );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a text: Buona notte Habras
{ a: 3 } { b: 2 } { e: 1 } { h: 1 } { n: 2 } { o: 2 } { r: 1 } { s: 1 } { t: 2 } { u: 1 } NULL
```